# Getting results from multiple apply_async as they become available

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I have multiple workers each with their own queue.  They are all running tasks using apply_async.

How can I get the results of each task as they become available, the order in which they complete is basically random.

Any idea how to do this without using loop with sleep?

```
# task.py
@app.task
def mytask()
  n = random.randrange(1,10)
  time.sleep(n)
  return n
```

```
task1 = worker1.mytask.apply_async(queue='queue1')
task2 = worker2.mytask.apply_async(queue='queue2')
task3 = worker3.mytask.apply_async(queue='queue3')
```

Want the app to stop until one of the task completes and return results of the first task.  If I add .join() I have to use on all 3 and not knowing will finish first, have to wait till all 3 returns results.

edited: added example code

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can group them using some of the [Celery workflow](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html) primitives, the most obvious one is a [Group](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups).